# Nice size of image of graph by staying the table at the same page

Tags: vertical-alignment

If I make the height of the image more than 3cm, the table will automatically go to newpage which I don't want to. How can I make the table stay while having a nice image at the top-right of the paper?

```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \usepackage{graphicx}
   \begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \noindent \noindent\begin{minipage}{.6\textwidth} 
    \textbf{Standard Normal Cumulative Probability Table}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[height=3cm]{ztable.png}
      \end{minipage}


     \begin{center}


    \begin{tabular}{c|c c c c c c c c c c c}

     \multicolumn{11}{c}{\textbf{Cumulative probabilities for POSITIVE z-values are                  
     shown in the following table}} \\ \hline
    $\textbf{z}$&\textbf{0.00}&\textbf{0.01}&\textbf{0.02}&\textbf{0.03}&\textbf{0.04}&\textbf{0.05}&\textbf{0.06}&\textbf{0.07}&\textbf{0.08}&\textbf{0.09}\\
     \hline \hline 
    \textbf{0.0}&0.5000&0.5040&0.5080&0.5120&0.5160&0.5199&0.5239&0.5279&0.5319&0.5359\\
    \textbf{0.1}&0.5398&0.5438&0.5478&0.5517&0.5557&0.5596&0.5636&0.5675&0.5714&0.5753\\
    \textbf{0.2}&0.5793&0.5832&0.5871&0.5910&0.5948&0.5987&0.6026&0.6064&0.6103&0.6141\\
        \textbf{0.3}&0.6179&0.6217&0.6255&0.6293&0.6331&0.6368&0.6406&0.6443&0.6480&0.6517\\
        \textbf{0.4}&0.6554&0.6591&0.6628&0.6664&0.6700&0.6736&0.6772&0.6808&0.6844&0.6879\\
       \textbf{0.5}&0.6915&0.6950&0.6985&0.7019&0.7054&0.7088&0.7123&0.7157&0.7190&0.7224\\
         \textbf{0.6}&0.7257&0.7291&0.7324&0.7357&0.7389&0.7422&0.7454&0.7486&0.7517&0.7549\\
         \textbf{0.7}&0.7580&0.7611&0.7642&0.7673&0.7703&0.7734&0.7764&0.7794&0.7823&0.7852\\
         \textbf{0.8}&0.7881&0.7910&0.7939&0.7967&0.7995&0.8023&0.8051&0.8078&0.8106&0.8133\\
        \textbf{0.9}&0.8159&0.8186&0.8212&0.8238&0.8264&0.8289&0.8315&0.8340&0.8365&0.8389\\
         \textbf{1.0}&0.8413&0.8438&0.8461&0.8485&0.8508&0.8531&0.8554&0.8577&0.8599&0.8621\\


      \end{tabular}
      \end{center}
      \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your question is quite hard to understand. Do you want the text "Standard Normal Cumulative Probability Table" and the "ztable.png" image side by side, at the top of the page, and to display below the table?

Comment: You can't as the `tabular` will not split. Use `longtable` instead.

Comment: Your problem is not reproducible with the given code.  Try to avoid that many blanklines, double `\noindent`, and two minipages side by side where one has 40 % text width and the other 100 %.

Comment: the minipage in the first part of your code are not doing anything very useful (the one that is `\textwidth` wide is not doning anything at all other than forcing a line break.  Why is this table not being set as a table with `begin{table}` and `\caption` ?

Comment: Yes, I would like to make the title and image side by side. Owh, I will try to use \begin{table} and \caption.